# How to work with Android Document tree and Sd Card?

Tags: android, sd-card

I have been working with a file manager app and I created copy, paste, rename etc. functions for the internal storage and then I tried to develop the same thing with the SD card but it fails. Then I researched and found I need to work with tree URI and ask for permission So I did that and now the app works for only the sd card root. for example I cannot get inside of a folder and create a new folder although i can create a folder in the root. I took the tree urii from `onActivityResult` and saved it in shared preference then I thought I can manipulate it and get to all the folders and files but its not possible ?

My Goal is as follows:
1. ask the user to select the root of sdcard for the first time and save tree uri in shared preference.

2. Use the following `generateCurrentURi()` function to generate the current uri whenever I want. I will use this Uri to `copy/paste/rename` etc.
3. The trouble is the following piece of code int he function always return the root URi

   ```
   pickedDirBase= DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, Uri.parse(documentFile.getUri().toString()));
   ```

Here goes the function

```
public Uri generateCurrentURi(){
    Uri uri;
    DocumentFile pickedDirBase= DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, Uri.parse(appPrefrences.getUri()));
    //index movement carries the document tree file positions like 0,1,2 that means
    // in the root 0=first folder, 1= root>1st folder> 2nd Foleder, 2= root>1st folder> 2nd Foleder>3rd Folder>,
    // The documentFile[ ] has all the files/folders of a specific directory. like 0,1,2... so with the
    //indexMovement arraylist I can easily go throught he directory
    for(int i=0;i<indexMovement.size();i++){
        DocumentFile[] documentFiles = pickedDirBase.listFiles() ;
        DocumentFile documentFile = documentFiles[indexMovement.get(i)];

        Uri u=documentFile.getUri();
        DocumentFile[] documentFile2=documentFile.listFiles();

        pickedDirBase= DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, Uri.parse(documentFile.getUri().toString()));

    }
    uri=pickedDirBase.getUri();
    currentUri=uri;
    return uri;
}
```

Here is the the onActivityResult() please check

```
public void access(){

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
    // it would be "*/*".
    //intent.setType("*/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 42);
}

boolean deletebuttonclicked=false;
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultData) {
    if (requestCode == 42) {
        treeUri = resultData.getData();
        appPrefrences.setUri(treeUri);
        //save it
        manipulator.saveCurrentUri(treeUri);
        //appChooserAppearsOnce=true;
        appPrefrences.sdPermissionGranted(true);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(treeUri,Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION & Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION );
        }

        makeToast("Access Granted");
        Log.v(TAG,"reached");
    }

}
```

Comment: `ask the user to select the root of sdcard for the first time and save tree uri in shared preference.`. Well start with telling what exactly you do there. Add it to your post please.

Comment: `I took the tree urii from onActivity result and saved it in shared preference then I thought I can manipulate it and get to all the folders and files but its not possible ?`. Yes of course that is possible. But your code is pretty unclear.  If you saved the string `data.getData().toString()` to shared preferences then you get the uri back with `Uri.parse(.that samestring from shared preferences....)`.

Comment: `for(int i=0;i<indexMovement.size();i++){` Remove that. It is pretty unclear where that loop comes from.

Comment: `DocumentFile[] documentFiles = pickedDirBase.listFiles() ;`. Ok. Does it list? Now make a loop to print all the uris of documentFiles[].

Comment: `public Uri generateCurrentURi()` ?? I dont know what you want with that function. You could much better make a function `listFiles(String uristring)`. Where usristring is the string from shared preferences.

Comment: You added comments to your post. But generateCurrentUri() still is a nonsense function. Please take a break and make that listFiles() function and post it here.

Comment: The thing is once I get the documentFiles[] from the pickedDirBase I can get all the Uris of  a directory, suppose my indexMovement array has (5,3,2) so the loop will woork like first it will got to root> then it will get uri from documentFile[] and get uri of 6th directory> then create the pickedDirBase with that URi. The trouble is it does not create pickedDirBase with the 6th directories URI. I always gives me the URi of the root.

Comment: Nonsense code to begin with. Do away with indexMovement variable and make a loop for documentFiles[].

Comment: Make a recursive  listFiles(DocumentFile docFile) function to print all the uris of all folders and files recursive.

Comment: I dont think you understood my intentions, Anyways suppose u have a uri from documentFile[]. can you create a directory in that folder ?? If you can share code

Comment: Have a look at DocumentFile.createFile().

Comment: `pickedDirBase= DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, Uri.parse(documentFile.getUri().toString()));` That should be more like `pickedDirBase=documentFile`. The code in between can be removed.

Comment: Your code will have IndexOutOfBoundsExceptions.

Comment: Its creating file on my root sdcard directory. but I want to create a folder inside another folder of root folder suppose its called "KBB". I get the directories list and find the Uri of  "KBB" and try to create a folder insode there but it does not create folder there rather it creates folder in the root. no matter i put in the uri section of the following code it only gives access to the root `pickedDirBase= DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, Uri.parse(documentFile.getUri().toString()));`

Comment: documentFiles[0].createFile(...) will create a file in that folder. Well if it is a folder.

Comment: Have you worked with the android sdcard before? Its very different than working with the internal storage.

Comment: Yes. I made already a SAF explorer.

Comment: Can you share code ?

Comment: `documentFiles[0].createFile(...) will create a file in that folder. Well if it is a folder.` Did you try that? Well try!

Comment: yes you are not getting me.I get the directory from the  following code  `DocumentFile documentFile = documentFiles[indexMovement.get(i)];'`And then I try to create another DocumentFIle using the  following code`'pickedDirBase= DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, Uri.parse(documentFile.getUri().toString()));` The thing is no matter what I do **pickedDirBase** always contains the uri of the root folder even though `documentFile.getUri().toString()` shows a diferent Uri

Comment: Please do not repeat your code. Just try `DocumentFile[] documentFiles = pickedDirBase.listFiles() ; documentFiles[0].createFile(...);`.

Comment: Yes i get you. And i can confirm that it does not work the way you think it should work. So then just try what i suggested. Things go indeed very different.

Comment: what if I want to create a folder inside another folder. i just want a piece of code that can tell me how the hierarchy work. `DocumentFile[] documentFiles = pickedDirBase.listFiles() ; documentFiles[0].createFile(...);`this line will create a file inside the 1st folder of root but what if i want to create a file inside a directory that reside in the 1st folder of root? Just answer this question and I will understand rest

Comment: In principe you should first get a DocumentFile instance for that directory in that folder. As then you can use createFile() on it. If you have a DocumentFile instance for that folder you can obtain one for that subdirectory using DocumentFile.findFile().

Answer (score 1):

I have searched in the internet a lot to figure out a good solution but seems like all the solutions are cluttered and I could not even I find a solution that suits. Then I strated reading the SAF documentation I found a solution to my problem. now I can copy/paste/delete inside the sdcard. I am sharing my solution to everyone in need

To solve the problem fist you need get the permission from the user to access sd card and you do it by the following method method in your activity

```
boolean deletebuttonclicked=false;
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultData) {
    if (requestCode == 42) {
        treeUri = resultData.getData();
        appPrefrences.setUri(treeUri);
        //save it
        manipulator.saveCurrentUri(treeUri);

        //appChooserAppearsOnce=true;
        appPrefrences.sdPermissionGranted(true);
        manipulator.InitializeCurrentDirAfterPermission();
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(treeUri,Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION & Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION );
        }
        //DocumentFile pickedDir = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, treeUri);

        // Create a new file and write into it
        // DocumentFile newFile = pickedDir.createFile("text/plain", "My Novel");
        if(deletebuttonclicked){
            deleteDirectory();
        }else if(newFolderClick){
            String foldername = "New Folder2";
            DocumentFile pickedDir = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, Uri.parse(appPrefrences.getUri()));
            pickedDir.createDirectory(foldername);
            Log.v(TAG, "Directory is created");
            Toast.makeText(SdCardFunctionality.this, "New Folder created with the name:"
                    + foldername, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        //permissiongranted = true;
        makeToast("Access Granted");
        Log.v(TAG,"reached");
    }

}
```

Now once you get the permission you will have to save it in shared prefs. Like I did in onActivityResults(). Now use the following class to control it

```
public class SdCardDirectoryManipulator {

/////////////*********** DIRECTORY HANDLER ***********////////////
String currentTreeDir="";
DocumentFile pickedDir=null;
boolean firstTime=true;
AppPrefrences appPrefrences;
Context context;
SdCardFunctionality act;

public Uri currentUri;



//this will maintain all the directory we have moved
//at first its emplty if we get in a directory it will save the index of the dir we clicked
ArrayList<Integer> indexMovement=new ArrayList<>();
//index movement and index Uri are correspondant
//ArrayList<Uri> indexURi=new ArrayList<>();

public SdCardDirectoryManipulator(Context ctx, SdCardFunctionality acitvity){
    appPrefrences=new AppPrefrences(ctx);
    context=ctx;
    act=acitvity;

    if(appPrefrences.getUri()!=null)
    currentUri=Uri.parse(appPrefrences.getUri());
}

public void saveCurrentUri(Uri uri){
    currentUri=uri;
}

DocumentFile currentDir;
public void saveIndex(int index){
    indexMovement.add(index);
    currentDir=generateCurrentURi();
    //indexURi.add(uri);
}

public void clearIndexes(){
    indexMovement.clear();
}

//back press treatment
public void backPressed(){
int size=indexMovement.size();
if(size>0){
indexMovement.remove(indexMovement.get(size-1));
    currentDir=generateCurrentURi();
}
}

public void InitializeCurrentDirAfterPermission(){
    currentDir=generateCurrentURi();
}

//it will generate the current uri
public DocumentFile generateCurrentURi(){
    DocumentFile doc;
    DocumentFile pickedDirBase= DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, Uri.parse(appPrefrences.getUri()));
    //index movement carries the document tree file positions like 0,1,2 that means
    // in the root 0=first folder, 1= root>1st folder> 2nd Foleder, 2= root>1st folder> 2nd Foleder>3rd Folder>,
    // The documentFile[ ] has all the files/folders of a specific directory. like 0,1,2... so with the
    //indexMovement arraylist I can easily go throught he directory
documentFiles[indexMovement.get(i)];
//
//            DocumentFile[] documentFiles2=documentFile.listFiles();
//
//            //documentFiles2[0].createDirectory("Mir");
//
//            Uri u=documentFile.getUri();
//            DocumentFile[] documentFile2=documentFile.listFiles();
//
//            pickedDirBase= DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context,         Uri.parse(documentFile.getUri().toString()));
//
//        }
//        uri=pickedDirBase.getUri();
//        currentUri=uri;
//        return uri;


    doc=giveMeCurrentDocumentDirectory(0,pickedDirBase);
    return doc;

}

//call d with the root
public DocumentFile giveMeCurrentDocumentDirectory(int pos,DocumentFile d){
    DocumentFile d1=null;
    if(indexMovement.size()==0)
        return d;
    if(pos<indexMovement.size()){
        int fileindex= indexMovement.get(pos);
        d1=d.listFiles()[fileindex];

    }
    if(pos+1==indexMovement.size()){
        return d1;
    }else
        pos++;

    return giveMeCurrentDocumentDirectory(pos,d1);

}


//////////////////////////////// FUNCTIONS //////////////////////
public void createNewFolder(){
    String foldername = "New Folder2";
    if(currentDir!=null) {
        currentDir.createDirectory(foldername);
        currentDir=generateCurrentURi();
    }
}

public void renameFolder(String name){
    if(!act.multiselect.isEmpty() && currentDir!=null){
        int index=act.myList2.indexOf(act.multiselect.get(0));
        DocumentFile f=currentDir.listFiles()[index];
        f.renameTo(name);
        //upgrade current directory otherwise new files wont be added
        currentDir=generateCurrentURi();
    }
}

//delete
public boolean deleteFiles(){
    boolean deleted=false;
    if(!act.multiselect.isEmpty())
    for(int i=0;i<act.multiselect.size();i++){
        int index=act.myList2.indexOf(act.multiselect.get(i));
        DocumentFile f=currentDir.listFiles()[index];

        f.delete();
        deleted=true;
    }

    if(deleted) {
        currentDir = generateCurrentURi();
    }
    act.clearMultiSelect(1);

    return deleted;
}

DocumentFile oldCopyDir=null;
ArrayList<DocumentFile> files=new ArrayList<>();

public void copyFilesLoc(){
oldCopyDir=currentDir;
    for(int i=0; i<act.copyTask.size();i++) {
        int index = act.myList2.indexOf(act.copyTask.get(i));
        DocumentFile file = oldCopyDir.listFiles()[index];
        files.add(file);
    }
}


public void copyFiles(boolean isCopy){

    for(int i=0; i<files.size();i++) {
        DocumentFile file=files.get(i);
        InputStream inStream = null;
        OutputStream outStream = null;
        boolean isDirectory = file.isDirectory();
        if (isDirectory) {
            currentDir.createDirectory(file.getName());
        } else
            currentDir.createFile("", file.getName());
        //currentDir=generateCurrentURi();
        DocumentFile d = currentDir.findFile(file.getName());


        //currentDir= generateCurrentURi();
        //DocumentFile d=currentDir.
        try {

            //String st=readFileContent(file.getUri());
            if (!isDirectory) {
                inStream =
                        context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(file.getUri());
                outStream =
                        (FileOutputStream) context.getContentResolver().openOutputStream(d.getUri());
                byte[] buffer = new byte[16384];
                int bytesRead;
                while ((bytesRead = inStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (!isDirectory) {
                    inStream.close();

                    outStream.close();
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    }
    //the cut treatment
    if(!isCopy){
        for(DocumentFile d: files){
            d.delete();
        }
    }

    files.clear();
}


public void makeToast(String str){
    Toast.makeText(context, str,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

}
```

index movement carries the document tree file positions like 0,1,2 that means in the root 0=first folder, 1= root>1st folder> 2nd Foleder, 2= root>1st folder> 2nd Foleder>3rd Folder>,The documentFile[ ] has all the files/folders of a specific directory. like 0,1,2... so with the indexMovement arraylist I can easily go through the directory.
whenever a user clicks on a folder you save its index by calling the saveIndex() method of the SdCardManipulator class. So you will have like 3,2,4 etc. which means from the root go to 4th directory then in that folder got to 3rd directory then in that folder go to 5 th directory. YOU MUST SAVE THE ROOD OF SDCARD IN THE SHARED PREFS. SO TAHT YOU CAN TRAVERSE IT USING THE generateCurrentURi() OF MANIPULATOR CLASS

I KNOW THIS CODE WILL SAVE A LOT OF TIME TO SOME DEVELOPER. PELASE GIVE ME A UPVOTE IF YOU FIND IT HELPFUL